# Is it possible to make sauerkraut ferment faster?

Tags: sauerkraut

I am trying to make Sauerkraut, and it's quite frustrating since many internet guides say I need to wait about 14 or more days to have the ideal Kraut. Is there anyway to speed up the process? Else, if I were to make subsequent batches, could I use the liquid inside the jar to ferment that faster?

Answer (score 7):

The idea is to promote the growth of lactobacillus, ideally in the temperature range of 60 - 70F.  The warmer temperature, the faster it will ferment.  However, above 75 degrees and you are likely to be promoting the growth of other undesirable bacteria, which will influence the flavor and texture of the sauerkraut.  It takes time. If you want delicious sauerkraut you will need to embrace the process.

You can indeed use some of the liquid in the jar to get the fermentation process started more quickly, but it will still take a few weeks for quality kraut.  The best way to deal with the issue you raise is to start multiple batches several days apart.  You will have to wait for the first batch, but since you will have started several batches spaced by days or weeks, subsequent batches will be ready when you are.